# A dual space to the formal power series

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

I have the following topological question

Consider finite dimensional $\mathbb{k}$-vector spaces: $V_k=\mathbb{k}\langle e_1,\ldots, e_k\rangle $ endowed with discrete topology.

Consider an inverse limit of the system $V_k \to V_{k-1}$ defined by the formula $e_i \mapsto e_i,  i<k$ and $e_k \mapsto 0.$ Then the limit $V_\infty$ is a topological vector space. It is in fact the space of formal power series with order metric.

What is the dimension of the space of continuous linear functions on $V_\infty$ with values in the field $\mathbb{k}$ endowed with discrete topology. I think it should be at least continuum, since we can take the linear independent set of functions dual to the basis of $V_\infty$, which is quite clearly continuum-dimensional.

But maybe I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: Suppose you want to define a functional with value $1$ at every $e_i$. Can you? Seems to me that the only continuous function to a *discrete* group should be zero for all but finitely many $x_i$. If that’s right, the dimension will be countable-infinite.

Comment: @Lubin unfortunately, I don't know why this functional could not be defined...

Comment: Isn't $V_{\infty}$ just $\mathbb{k}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, I think it is, sorry for overcomplicating things

Comment: So every continuous function depends only on finitely many coordinates, and the dual space is $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{k}$.